# Populate one table with selected data from two others tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a table that I am trying to populate with our open tickets and the last followup they received, columns below, this is called "glpi_plugin_ns_followup":

```
ticket_number[int(11)], datetime_created[datetime], requester[int(11)], title[longtext], description[longtext], followup_datetime[datetime], last_followup[longtext], technician_user[int(11)]
```

The tables I am pulling from are glpi_tickets and glpi_ticketfollowups

glpi_tickets

```
id[int(11)], entities_id[int(11)], name[varchar(255)], date[datetime], closedate[datetime], solvedate[datetime], date_mod[datetime], users_id_lastupdater[int(11)], status[int(11)], users_id_recipient[int(11)], requesttypes_id[int(11)], content, urgency[int(11)], impact[int(11)], priority[int(11)], itilcategories_id[int(11)], type[int(11)], solutiontypes_id[int(11)], solution, global_validation[int(11)], slas_id[int(11)], slalevels_id[int(11)], due_date[datetime], begin_waiting_date[datetime], sla_waiting_duration[int(11)], waiting_duration[int(11)], close_delay_stat[int(11)], solve_delay_stat[int(11)], takeintoaccount_delay_stat[int(11)], actiontime[int(11)], is_deleted[tinyint(1)], locations_id[int(11)], validation_percent[int(11)]
```

glpi_ticketfollowups

```
id[int(11)], tickets_id[int(11)], date[datetime], users_id[int(11)], content[longtext], is_private[tinyint(11)], requesttypes_id[int(11)]
```

The common identifier across all three are as follows:

glpi_tickets = id

glpi_ticketfollowups = tickets_id

glpi_plugin_ns_followup = ticket_number

I've managed to insert the first five columns by using the below query:

```
TRUNCATE glpi_plugin_ns_followup;
INSERT INTO glpi_plugin_ns_followup (ticket_number, datetime_created, requester, title, description)
SELECT Id, date, users_id_recipient, name, content FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
WHERE is_deleted = 0 and status !=6 and status !=5;
```

However I am struggling to fill in the last 3 columns with the relevant updates, so far I have tried using this code but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE glpi_plugin_ns_followup 
    SET followup_datetime = (SELECT date from glpi_ticketfollowups where glpi_ticketfollowups.tickets_id = glpi_plugin_ns_followup.ticket_number),
        last_followup = (SELECT content from glpi_ticketfollowups where glpi_ticketfollowups.tickets_id = glpi_plugin_ns_followup.ticket_number),
        technician_user = (SELECT users_id from glpi_ticketfollowups where glpi_ticketfollowups.tickets_id = glpi_plugin_ns_followup.ticket_number)
```

This gives me the response:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Which it should as I'm trying to update multiple rows, or the error may be because there are multiple followups per ticket. I have a feeling I may be going at this from entirely the wrong angle. If someone can assist me and put me back on the right track that would be much appreciated.

I can supply sample data if needed but it will take a while to gather and censor it ;-)

EDIT: As per Kamil's suggestions with max() I have managed to get the date fields to work:

```
UPDATE glpi_plugin_ns_followup 
SET followup_datetime = (SELECT max(date) from glpi_ticketfollowups where glpi_ticketfollowups.tickets_id = glpi_plugin_ns_followup.ticket_number GROUP BY tickets_id)
```

However I cannot get it to work for content or technician_user, if I can pull the newest date/times for the last time a followup was added to a ticket can I modify anything to pull in the content and technician_user as well?

EDIT2: tried adding `GROUP BY t.id;` at the end of your initial solution but it does not use the newest followup for the tickets.

EDIT3:Have tried the following, it pulls in the correct date/time but the wrong content

```
    TRUNCATE glpi_plugin_ns_followup;
INSERT INTO glpi_plugin_ns_followup (ticket_number, datetime_created, requester, title, description, followup_datetime, last_followup, technician_user)
SELECT 
  t.id, t.date, t.users_id_recipient, t.name, t.content,
  tf.datetime, tf.content, tf.users_id
FROM 
  glpi.glpi_tickets t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(date) as datetime, content, users_id, tickets_id
    FROM glpi_ticketfollowups
    GROUP BY tickets_id) tf ON
    t.id = tf.tickets_id    
WHERE 
  t.is_deleted = 0 
  and t.status NOT IN (5,6)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Thanks
iFr4g

Comment: use group by functionality in sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine both of those statements into one and only issue `INSERT` command. However, this will multiply your rows from `glpi_tickets` if more than one matching row exists in `glpi_ticketfollowups` fetched with the condition `t.id = tf.tickets_id`.

I've added a `LEFT JOIN` and slightly changed the `WHERE` clause to save some coding.

```
INSERT INTO glpi_plugin_ns_followup (ticket_number, datetime_created, requester, title, description, followup_datetime, last_followup, technician_user)
SELECT 
  t.id, t.date, t.users_id_recipient, t.name, t.content,
  tf.date, tf.content, tf.users_id
FROM 
  glpi.glpi_tickets t
  LEFT JOIN glpi_ticketfollowups tf ON
    t.id = tf.tickets_id
WHERE 
  t.is_deleted = 0 
  and t.status NOT IN (5,6)
```

If you need only one row per `glpi_tickets` table in your destination table, then what you are looking for is a way to get only one row from `glpi_ticketfollowups` per a ticket. This could be achieved by adding a `GROUP BY` clause and choosing appropriate logic of getting one value, for example: `max()` or `min()`. Remember, that issuing an aggregate function over 3 values will not bring you result from one row, but an aggregate result from entire dataset. This could be avoided by doing it the way you started - insert and update by adding a LIMIT clause.

---

*Edit after comments*:

Since you need last followup for a every ticket and you are sure that are dates per ticket are unique you could do a self-join calculating maximum date per ticket in `glpi_ticketfollowups` and then `LEFT JOIN` that to your `glpi_tickets` table:

```
INSERT INTO glpi_plugin_ns_followup (ticket_number, datetime_created, requester, title, description, followup_datetime, last_followup, technician_user)
SELECT 
  t.id, t.date, t.users_id_recipient, t.name, t.content,
  tf.date, tf.content, tf.users_id
FROM 
  glpi.glpi_tickets t
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT allf.tickets_id, allf.date, allf.content, allf.users_id
    FROM glpi_ticketfollowups allf
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT tickets_id, MAX(date) AS date
      FROM glpi_ticketfollowups
      GROUP BY tickets_id
      ) lastf ON
        allf.tickets_id = lastf.tickets_id
        AND allf.date = lastf.date
    ) tf ON
    t.id = tf.tickets_id
WHERE 
  t.is_deleted = 0 
  and t.status NOT IN (5,6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes I only need one row per ticket in the destination, I would need the latest followup, so would I `GROUP BY` `tickets_id` and then use `max(date)` to get the most recent result?

Comment: That depends what you mean by latest followup. If you mean latest row, then are you sure that `tickets_id, date` pair is unique? If not, check for it - this may simplify the issue. If you mean just highest date, content and users_id (which doesn't equal the former case) then just use max.

Comment: Tried your initial solution but it has multiple lines per ticket, but is nearly doing what I want :)

Comment: Do you have unique `(tickets_id, date)` pairs? I'm asking again :) Or are there any tickets with the same date?

Comment: Hi Kamil, this is what I'm working with (http://imgur.com/a/HHL4a) the `tickets_id` does appear multiple times, but each time it does it has a unique `date` hope that helps :)

Comment: @iFr4g I've added approach which should get you going. Based on unique dates from followups per ticket it retrieves that latest followup.

Comment: @iFr4g Looking at your edit3: If you don't include every field in GROUP BY that is not aggregated with a function you are going to get random values. Although MySQL allows it, it's discouraged to use it. Other DBMS like Postgres don't even allow it.

Comment: Top notch stuff Kamil, that's done exactly what I wanted, thanks for your help :)